# FFmpeg fails with av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe (error code=256) randomly

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert audio data from a file or stream to PCM to convert it to a special OGG/OPUS format to stream it to a special device. The conversion runs in its own thread.

Sometimes it is working as it should, but sometimes mostly just after the transcoding starts it fails.

I already tried to change the buffer size, but nothing changed. What can I do to prevent the broken pipe errors and make the transcoding more stable?

> av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe
>
> Error writing trailer of pipe:: Broken pipe
>
> Stopped ffmpeg with error code=256...

```
FILE *ffmpeg_decode_audio_start_skip(const char *input_source, size_t skip_seconds)
{
    char ffmpeg_command[1024];
    snprintf(ffmpeg_command, sizeof(ffmpeg_command), "ffmpeg -i \"%s\" -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -ss %" PRIuSIZE " -", input_source, skip_seconds);

    FILE *ffmpeg_pipe = NULL;

    ffmpeg_pipe = osPopen(ffmpeg_command, "r");
    if (ffmpeg_pipe == NULL)
    {
        return ffmpeg_pipe;
    }
    return ffmpeg_pipe;
}

error_t ffmpeg_stream(char *source, char *target_taf, size_t skip_seconds, bool_t *active)
{
    FILE *ffmpeg_pipe = NULL;
    error_t error = NO_ERROR;
    ffmpeg_pipe = ffmpeg_decode_audio_start_skip(source, skip_seconds);
    if (ffmpeg_pipe == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    //toniefile_t *taf = [...]

    int16_t sample_buffer[2 * 4096];
    size_t samples = sizeof(sample_buffer) / sizeof(uint16_t);
    size_t blocks_read = 0;

    *active = true;
    while (*active)
    {
        error = ffmpeg_decode_audio(ffmpeg_pipe, sample_buffer, samples, &blocks_read);
        if (error != NO_ERROR && error != ERROR_END_OF_STREAM)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (error == ERROR_END_OF_STREAM)
        {
            error = NO_ERROR;
            break;
        }
        //toniefile_encode(taf, sample_buffer, blocks_read / 2);
    }

    ffmpeg_decode_audio_end(ffmpeg_pipe, error);
    //toniefile_close(taf);

    return error;
}

error_t ffmpeg_decode_audio(FILE *ffmpeg_pipe, int16_t *buffer, size_t size, size_t *blocks_read)
{
    if (ffmpeg_pipe == NULL)
        return ERROR_ABORTED;

    *blocks_read = 0;
    size_t chunk_size = 4096;
    while (*blocks_read < size)
    {
        size_t remaining_samples = size - *blocks_read;
        size_t samples_to_read = (remaining_samples < chunk_size) ? remaining_samples : chunk_size;

        size_t read = fread(&buffer[*blocks_read], sizeof(int16_t), samples_to_read, ffmpeg_pipe);

        if (read == 0)
        {
            if (*blocks_read > 0)
            {
                return NO_ERROR;
            }
            else
            {
                return ERROR_END_OF_STREAM; // End of audio data
            }
        }
        *blocks_read += read;
    }
    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: Why not encode to OPUS straight with ffmpeg?

Comment: The pages need to be padded to 4k bytes. And the coding is also used for browser based ogg/opus encoding, as the browser can decode to pcm, so ffmpeg is not needed.